# The error "You can't use 'the character [...]' after \the" keeps appearing when I use expl3 and I don't know why

Tags: expl3

I doing some experiments with `expl3` and I wanted to create a command that allows me to create different types of references for each type of object being referenced. Also, I wanted to create a easy way to create hyperlinks for exercises in a list.
So I came up with the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{expl3}

% For the \exc command ----------------------------------------------

\newcounter{exercises}
\setcounter{exercises}{0}
\newcounter{letter}[exercises]

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l_exc_arg_tl
  \seq_new:N \l_exc_args_seq
  \tl_new:N \l_exc_first_arg_tl
  \tl_new:N \l_exc_second_arg_tl
  \newcommand{\exc}[1]{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_exc_arg_tl {#1}
    \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_exc_arg_tl {.} {% Used between the number and the letter of the exercise
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_exc_args_seq {.} {#1}
      \exc_write_number_letter:N \l_exc_args_seq
    }{
      \exc_write_letter:V \l_exc_arg_tl
    }
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \exc_write_number_letter:N #1 {
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_exc_args_seq \l_exc_first_arg_tl
    \seq_get_right:NN \l_exc_args_seq \l_exc_second_arg_tl
    \exc_write_exercise:VV \l_exc_first_arg_tl \l_exc_second_arg_tl
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \exc_write_exercise:VV #1#2 {
    \stepcounter{exercises}
    \setcounter{exercises}{#1}
    \refstepcounter{letter}
    \exc_write_label:VV {#1} {#2}
    \writeExercise{#1}\space\writeItem{#2}
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \exc_write_letter:V #1 {
    \refstepcounter{letter}
    \exc_write_label:VV {\theexercises} {#1}
    \writeItem{#1}
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \exc_write_label:VV #1#2 {
    \label{exc:#1.#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\writeExercise}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1.}%
}%
\newcommand*{\writeItem}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1)}%
}%

% -------------------------------------------------------------------

% New definition for \Ref -------------------------------------------

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l_label_type_tl
  \tl_new:N \l_label_name_tl
  \seq_new:N \l_separated_arg_seq
  \seq_new:N \g_supported_types_seq
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_supported_types_seq {eq}
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_supported_types_seq {exc}
  \renewcommand{\Ref}[1]{
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_separated_arg_seq {:} {#1}
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_separated_arg_seq \l_label_type_tl
    \seq_get_right:NN \l_separated_arg_seq \l_label_name_tl
    \seq_if_in:NVTF \g_supported_types_seq {\l_label_type_tl} {
      \tl_if_in:NnT \l_label_type_tl {eq} {
        \rf_eq_ref:V \l_label_name_tl
      }
      \tl_if_eq:NnT \l_label_type_tl {exc} {
        \rf_exc_ref:V \l_label_name_tl
      }
    }{
      \rf_ref:VV \l_label_type_tl \l_label_name_tl
    }
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \rf_ref:VV #1#2 {
    \ref{#1:#2}
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \rf_eq_ref:V #1 {
    \eqref{eq:#1}
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \rf_exc_ref:V #1 {
    \seq_clear:N \l_exc_args_seq
    \tl_set:Nn \l_exc_arg_tl {#1}
    \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_exc_arg_tl {.} {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_exc_args_seq {.} {#1}
      \seq_get_left:NN \l_exc_args_seq \l_exc_first_arg_tl
      \seq_get_right:NN \l_exc_args_seq \l_exc_second_arg_tl
      \rf_write_exc_ref:VV \l_exc_first_arg_tl \l_exc_second_arg_tl
    }{
      \tl_set: \l_exc_fisrt_arg {\theexercises}
      \rf_write_exc_ref:VV \l_exc_first_arg_tl {#1}
    }
  }
  \cs_new:Npn \rf_write_exc_ref:VV #1#2 {
    \hyperref[exc:#1.#2]{\textbf{#1.}\space\textbf{#2)}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% -------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\exc{1. a}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:equation}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\exc{b}

\Ref{eq:equation}

\Ref{exc:b}

\exc{2. a}

\Ref{exc:2.a}

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry it is a mess, but I hope you can understand.

The desired output would then be:
[image: Desired output.]

where output in the fourth, fifth and seventh lines should be clickable.

The problem is that it won't compile. In the example given, the error message is: "You can't use 'the letter e' after \the". The same error occurs for whatever character ends up being the first in the argument of `\Ref`, e.g. the code `\Ref{fig:figure}` would generate the error "You can't use 'the letter f' after \the".

If I change the first line in the definition of `\Ref` to `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_separated_arg_seq {:} {#1}`, it will compile but the code will not recognize the character ':' and thus it will not split the argument. If I change it to `\seq_set_split:NnV \l_separated_arg_seq {:} #1`, it will just take the first character as an argument.

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The first line in the definition of `\Ref` should probably be `\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_separated_arg_seq {:} {#1}` instead of `\seq_set_split:NnV \l_separated_arg_seq {:} {#1}` (`Nnn` instead of `NnV`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You should probably post less code, and say more what it is trying to do. I haven't run it but for example `\exc_write_label:VV {#1} {#2}` is wrong, V arguments should be a single token not a brace group (although usually you can get away with that)  `:` in expl3 code is a letter (catcode 11) but in your document it is punctuation (catcode 12) so these are different tokens which is probably your main issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks! Then I should use `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_some_token_list_tl {<catcode setup>} {#1}`, right? In this case, what whould be the catcode setup?

Comment: Also directly defining a `:VV` macro seems strange as well. Normally you'd define a macro `\foo_bar:nn` expecting normal arguments, and if you need a `:VV` variant you'd generate it using `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo_bar:nn { VV }`.